# configuartion settings for JAMon in jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, jamon

I am trying to configure jamon (http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/http_monitoring.html) in jboss 7. The configuration instructions that are given on jamon website are for older jboss (40.5/4.2). Can any one help me with the equivalent JAMon configuration settings in jboss 7.

```
JBoss 4.0.5/4.2 - Other versions may work too.
    Put jamon-2.7.jar (or higher) in the jboss instance 'lib' directory (ex. default/lib).
    Put jamon.war (or higher) in the jboss instance 'deploy' directory. (ex. default/deploy).
    Add the following Valve line to Tomcat's server.xml file (i.e. jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/server.xml). The 'Engine' line is used to show context.
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Valve className="com.jamonapi.http.JAMonTomcatValve"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice blog entry that details the steps to get Jamon running in  JBOSS 7 and WildFly.  It also shows how to monitor ebj's.

http://people.apache.org/~sgoeschl/blog/posts/jamon/wildfly/jboss/jamonapi-and-wildfly-as/

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy all jamon jars to jboss module/com/jamonapi/main
2. Add dependencies for servlet api in module.xml
3. Add com.jamonapi as a global module in standalone.xml
4. Add the valve entry in jboss-web.xml

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer got me partially there; here are my steps (including Paul's steps w/ some more detail)

```
mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/jamon/api/main
```

Copy all of the jamon jars to this directory

Add the following module.xml to the new directory created above.  *(Note that this assumes that you're using v2.80 so change the jar names appropriately.)*

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.jamon.api">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jamon-2.80.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jamon-osmon-2.80.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

Add the module to your `standalone.xml` file:

```
<server>
...
<profile>
    ...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
        ...
        <global-modules>
            ...
            <module name="com.jamon.api" slot="main"/>
        </global-modules>
    </subsystem>
</profile>
</server>
```

Deploy the `jamon.war` to your `deployments` directory